# Elixir Phoenix Plugs and where to place them

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm currently at learning Elixir Phoenix framework. I stuck at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/routing.html#forward now, it's about how to use `forward` command.

It's written there, that it's not neccessary to learn about Plugs now, so if I want to try out that `forward` command I can just copy their implementation of Plug **into my application**. But where exactly? I tried to search it out and tried to use what I found, but I am doing something wrong.

That's the scope from my `.\lib\hello_web\router.ex` file:

```
scope "/", HelloWeb do
  pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

  get "/", PageController, :index
  forward "/jobs", BackgroundJob.Plug, name: "Hello, Phoenix"
end
```

And that is the code for a Plug:

```
defmodule BackgroundJob.Plug do
  def init(opts), do: opts
  def call(conn, opts) do
    conn
    |> Plug.Conn.assign(:name, Keyword.get(opts, :name, "Background Job"))
    |> BackgroundJob.Router.call(opts)
  end
end

defmodule BackgroundJob.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug :match
  plug :dispatch

  get "/", do: send_resp(conn, 200, "Welcome to #{conn.assigns.name}")
  get "/active", do: send_resp(conn, 200, "5 Active Jobs")
  get "/pending", do: send_resp(conn, 200, "3 Pending Jobs")
  match _, do: send_resp(conn, 404, "Not found")
end
```

I supposed to know almost nothing about Plugs and Phoenix at all at this point, so it is probably something obvious, but I really stuck there for hours. Can anyone help me to find out where to place that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

You haven't posted what error you're getting, but I'm guessing your problem is module naming. In `phoenix`, modules used inside a `scope` block will get prefixed with the module name you give as an argument to that scope (`HelloWeb` in this case). So it should be enough to change the name of your plug module to `HelloWeb.BackgroundJob.Plug`. Alternatively you can not pass a scoping module to `scope`:

```
scope "/" do
  pipe_through :browser # Use the default browser stack

  get "/", HelloWeb.PageController, :index
  forward "/jobs", BackgroundJob.Plug, name: "Hello, Phoenix"
end
```

Note the change `PageController` -> `HelloWeb.PageController` in this case.

In terms of where to put it - any `.ex` file in `lib` will do, as elixir just compiles all of them. In fact you can just paste the code into your `router.ex` to test it out quickly. By convention the filename should follow the module name, so `HelloWeb.BackgroundJob.Plug` should live in `lib/hello_web/background_job/plug.ex`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works now!

But I think it would be useful to clarify here for anyone who will stuck into the same problem in future, that in `router.ex`'s `scope` `BackgroundJob.Plug` will not change into `HelloWeb.BackgroundJob.Plug`, otherwise it will cause an `(UndefinedFunctionError) function BackgroundJob.Router.call/2 is undefined (module BackgroundJob.Router is not available)` error.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I understand your confusion. 
It could be explained a little more clearly in the guides.

If you pass a module name to a scope, the passed in module name will get prefixed to all the modules in the scope.

So for example, assuming your passed in module name is `HelloWeb`, 
When you pass it into a scope like this:

```
scope "/", HelloWeb do
  ...
  get "/", PageController, :index
  forward "/jobs", BackgroundJob.Plug
end
```

the `"/"` route will look for `HelloWeb.PageController`
the `"/jobs"` route will look for `HelloWeb.BackgroundJob.Plug`

So to make your error go away, which I'm assuming is something like this:

```
helloweb.backgroundjob.plug.init/1 is undefined
```

You can either remove the passed in module name from the scope and prepend the module names by hand, leaving `BackgroundJob.Plug` unchanged like this:

```
scope "/",  do
  ...
  get "/", HelloWeb.PageController, :index
  forward "/jobs", BackgroundJob.Plug
end
```

Or, maybe save a little repetitive typing and add a "/jobs" scope instead, like this:

```
  scope "/", HelloWeb do
    ...
    get "/", PageController, :index
  end

  scope "/jobs" do
    forward "/", BackgroundJob.Plug, name: "Hello Phoenix"
  end
```

Please note, the `...` in the examples represents `pipe_through` methods and other routes which were not essential to convey the idea.

Hope that helps.